# google chrome full reset? huge bars and default zoom issues

Tags: google-chrome, restore, google

i guess the dog sat on the wireless keyboard when we were watching a movie and now the bars... address bar and tabs are like 1/5 of my screen. i tried to uninstall and reintall and tried the restore defaults button to no avail. help me before i reinstall my OS!! running 12.04 lts is that helps...

Answer (score 0):

The Google Chrome configuration is stored in `~/.config/google-chrome`. You can try deleting or moving that folder.